# Remove initial letter on similar reference in apacite

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, apacite, author

**Problem:**

Initials of authors are printed out if two authors has the same lastname when using `apacite`.

**References:**

```
@article{Klein14,
   author = {Klein, Lisl},
   title = {What do we actually mean by ‘sociotechnical’? On values, boundaries and the problems of language},
   journal = {Applied Ergonomics},
   volume = {45},
   number = {2014},
   pages = {137-142},
   year = {2014}
}
@article{Klein02,
   author = {Klein, Hans K. and Kleinman, Daniel Lee},
   title = {The social construction of technology: Structural considerations},
   journal = {Science, Technology, \& Human Values},
   volume = {27},
   number = {1},
   pages = {28-52},
   year = {2002}
}
```

**Outputs (when used with `\citep{}`):**

```
(L. Klein, 2014) (H. K. Klein & Kleinman, 2002)
```

**Desired output:**

```
(Klein, 2014) (Klein & Kleinman, 2002)
```

What I am looking for is to suppress initials in-text.

**Minimal Working Example (MWE):**

The minimal (kind of) working example does not work when using `filecontents` but for some reason works when I use .bib file in my project.

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Klein14,
   author = {Klein, Lisl},
   title = {What do we actually mean by ‘sociotechnical’? On values, boundaries and the problems of language},
   journal = {Applied Ergonomics},
   volume = {45},
   number = {2014},
   pages = {137-142},
   year = {2014}
}
@article{Klein02,
   author = {Klein, Hans K. and Kleinman, Daniel Lee},
   title = {The social construction of technology: Structural considerations},
   journal = {Science, Technology, \& Human Values},
   volume = {27},
   number = {1},
   pages = {28-52},
   year = {2002}
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}

\begin{document}

\citep{Klein02} \\ 
\citep{Klein14}

\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [tag:cross-referencing] is **not** meant for [tag:bibliographies] related questions

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Thanks, I'll keep that in mind for future reference.

Comment: The output you get is what is dictated by the APA, see http://blog.apastyle.org/apastyle/author-names/ and http://blog.apastyle.org/apastyle/2014/01/when-to-use-author-initials-for-text-citations.html for example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To avoid inserting the literals if the last names are not unique, you have to change the `apacite` style:

Search for the file `apacite.bst` in your TeX installation and copy it to your document directory as `apacite-no-initials.bst`.
Then you can open `apacite-no-initials.bst`. At the end of the file there are about 30 lines with `EXECUTE`, `ITERATE`, `REVERSE` and `SORT` statements.
There search for the lines

```
EXECUTE { init.initials }
ITERATE { check.add.initials }
EXECUTE { init.initials }
REVERSE { check.add.initials }
```

and delete them. After saving the changes you can use

```
\bibliographystyle{apacite-no-initials}
```

to use the modified style, which will never add initials in-text. Of course, this is no longer the APA style, so do not use this if you have to adhere to their style rules.

If you want to learn more about how style files work and how you can modify them, I recommend reading [Tame the BeaST](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/bibtex/tamethebeast/ttb_en.pdf).

Comment: That worked great, I also managed to find another solution, which also works. I did your initial steps but went inside the file and remove the content of the function `FUNCTION {check.add.initials.aut} { }` that is located around line 740-750.

Comment: Right, that is basically the same idea: My solution avoids calling the initials functionality, you just make it a noop. The advantage of the version in my answer is related to performance: your solution iterates two times over the entries, doing some checks and then doing nothing, while deleting the `ITERATE` and `REVERSE` avoids the iterations which makes it faster. Of course, this difference is most likely very small.